# Redirect top frame after log in

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I need a help.
My login box is in sidebar (included by php).
Function is
#

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#AuthorizationSuccess').hide();
$('#AuthorizationFail').hide();
$('#Button').click(function(){
    var Email       = $('#email_right').val();
    var Password    = $('#password_right').val();
    $.post( "/post.php", { Form: 'Login', RightBlock: '1', Email: Email, Password: Password, RedirectUrl: '<?php echo (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '/'; ?>'  },
        function(data){
            //alert (data);
            if(data=='success'){
                window.top.location.href = RedirectUrl; 
            }
            else{
                $('#AuthorizationFail').html('Error: ' + data);
                //$('#AuthorizationFail').show();
            }
        });
});
```

});

After user log in I need to redirect him to referer page (bc session name is not empty now and in that sidebar will be profile information) or reload sidebar page.

I was tried a lot of combinations of redirect...

`window.top.location.href = RedirectUrl;`

`window.top.location.href = '' + RedirectUrl + '';`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. Find a misstake. Right code below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#AuthorizationSuccess').hide();
$('#AuthorizationFail').hide();
$('#Button').click(function(){
    var Email       = $('#email_right').val();
    var Password    = $('#password_right').val();
    var RedirectUrl = '<?php echo (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '/'; ?>';
    $.post( "/post.php", { Form: 'Login', RightBlock: '1', Email: Email, Password: Password, RedirectUrl: RedirectUrl  },
        function(data){
            //alert (data);
            if(data=='success'){
                window.top.location.href = ''+RedirectUrl+''; 
            }
            else{
                $('#AuthorizationFail').html('Error: ' + data);
                //$('#AuthorizationFail').show();
            }
        });
});
```

});